# Is there a way to test that readme looks in other language before submitting translation?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, translation, localization, readme

I am adding the translation for my plugin's readme file in Spanish. I want to check if there is a way to test how my file will look on Wordpress site's page before submitting the translation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test it on WPReadme website, just paste your readme.txt file conrent and click Preview button: [WPReadme](https://wpreadme.com).

Comment: But my question is that how can I test in other languages apart from "English", if I have just po files for these languages that contain key-value pairs of string from "English->another language"

Comment: There is no other readme.txt preview tool anywhere. This can test complete readme.txt. I am not aware of the way to have readme translated the same way as the plugin PHP strings are.